# No matching distribution found for cv2

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Error when installing cv2

```
$ pip install cv2

ERROR: Introspect error on :1.1082:/modules/kwalletd5: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to open keyring: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.1082 was not provided by any .service files.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cv2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+No+matching+distribution+found+for+cv2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using python, use the following command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```